# How to access header files after installing with vcpkg?

Tags: visual-studio, icu, vcpkg

I'm trying to use ICU in a project in Visual Studio, which I am new to. The VS documentation encouraged me to use vcpkg, so I downloaded it. I then installed icu through vcpkg. I integrated vcpkg for my userspace.

I'm now able to include icu, but some classes aren't found. In this case I want to include normalizer2.h  but none of the syntax I try works. How can I include the individual header files within the icu package?

A snippet to demonstrate:

```
UErrorCode uErr=U_ZERO_ERROR;
const icu:: Normalizer2* UNormalizer = Normalizer2::getNFKCCasefoldInstance(uErr);
```

Throws the following error:

```
error C2039: 'Normalizer2': is not a member of 'icu'
```

Answer (score 3):

`#include <unicode/normalizer2.h>` should work if vcpkg is correctly set up. At least the file is installed into `<vcpkgroot>/installed/<triplet>/include/unicode/normalizer2.h`.
Make sure `<vcpkgroot>/installed/<triplet>/include/` is in your include paths (which it should if the integration is installed).

You might add `/showIncludes` as a compiler flag to see which include directories are searched.